# Custom theme: adding unwanted <p> tags in the content

Tags: php, theme-development, filters

I've built a custom theme and it works fine apart from WordPress injecting unwanted `<p>` tags on the page before the post loop starts. On top of that, it adds the word 'Save' eg: `<p>Save</p>`, I've tried using `remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );` in functions, but that only removes the `<p>` tags not the content.

```
<ul class="grid">
<?php query_posts('showposts=12&offset=6&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <h6>no more.....</h6>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php 

if( have_posts() ):

while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

  <li class="grid__item">
  <div class="roster__link">
      <img class="roster__image"><?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'URL', true );

         if ( $value ) {
             $url = esc_url( 'http://' . $value );
             if ( '' !== $url ) {
                 print "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$display";
             }
         }
      ?>

      <div class="text-wrap">
        <div class="text">
          <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </a>
  </li>


 <?php endwhile;

 endif;

?>

</ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood you questions. Can you please be more descriptive. Add screenshots if you can. Looks like screenshots will help in here

Comment: @MarutiMohanty thanks, added the code where the problem seems to stem from, I'm new to this so apologies if my answers aren't clear...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');

You can also look at your page.php or template file and investigate which elements/tags are being used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jake, tried that, it does remove the `<p>` tags but Wordpress still adds the word 'Save' to the page.

Comment: It most likely only shows if your the admin. Hard to debug without looking through all of your code, but try logging out/incognito and see if it shows up for normal users.

Comment: Figured it out, I was looping through things twice and  `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` was printing  `<p>Save</p>`  to the page. All fixed, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) glad you figured it out